# Application hang if i have more than 150 markers in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i am successfully displaying marker on a google map but problem is if i have more marker than application respond slowly.

```
public void setMarkerToPoint(ArrayList<BinForLocation> list)
{       
    for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        Log.v("log",""+list.get(i).getLongitude()); 
        Log.v("log",""+list.get(i).getLatitude()); 
        try
        {
            point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getLatitude()) * 1e6),(int) (Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getLongitude()) * 1e6));
            overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, list.get(i).getLocationName()+"_@_"+list.get(i).getLatitude()+"_@_"+list.get(i).getLongitude(), list.get(i).getAddress());
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("log",""+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getLatitude()) * 1e6),(int) (Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getLongitude()) * 1e6));
        CenterLocation(point);
        myMapController.setZoom(14);
    }
}
```

this function i am calling in oncreate()

Comment: Do you have 150 markers on 1 layer, or maybe 150 layers with 1 marker each?

Comment: this all you may be doing in main thread so the UI may become unresponsive . you can use handler for reflecting the respective so that main thread will have less over heads ........,, or paste your code here may be you need some optimization in your code ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've made your own customoverlay make sure that your addOverlay methode don't populate. Populate should first happen when all overlays has been added. If you populate each time you add you'll end up with many overlays on top of each other.

Make sure it uses 2 methods:

```
public void addOverlay(CustomOverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
}

public void populateOverlay() {
    populate();
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing first time, think its a google example or something which doesn't explain how it works properly.